# Properties of the differentiation map on real polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, elementary-set-theory

> Consider the linear map $D : \mathbb{R}[t] \to \mathbb{R}[t]$, given by formal differentiation.
>
> 1. Show that $D$ is surjective but not injective. Why is there no contradiction with the Rank-Nullity theorem?
> 2. **True or False:** for each $f \in \mathbb{R}[t]$, there is some positive integer $n$ so that $D^n(f) = 0$.

For (i) my thought was that there is no contradiction with the Rank-Nullity theorem because R[t] is not finite dimensional since it represents all polynomials possible. Also, to show it is not injective I said: $D(x^2)=2x=D(x^2+1)$. Though, since it is infinite I'm having a hard time proving it is surjective.

For (ii) my intuition says it's true (both of them because I honestly don't see the difference), since if you differentiate enough time, you'll get 0 at some point. But what would be a good way to mathematically prove this?

Thank you!

Comment: For surjectivity (i), consider antiderivative

Comment: Is it enough to say that any polynomial in the image corresponds to its antiderivative, which is a polynomial in the domain

Comment: I don't understand which are the assertions in (ii) that you deem true.

Comment: I modified my question a bit. I thought both assertions meant the same.

Comment: What do you think they mean, then?

Comment: That there exist a number (n) such that if you differentiate n times on a polynomials, you will get to 0.

Comment: I think I get it, one question is "Given a polynomial does there exist an n" and the other is "Does there exist an n that works for all polynomials"

Comment: Ohhh, yes you're right. But I think in both cases, if we have finite polynomials, it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prove surjectivity, let $p(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n p_k t^k \in \mathbb{R}[t]$ be an arbitrary element, and note that if $q(t) = \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{p_k}{k+1} t^{k+1} \in \mathbb{R}[t]$, then $D(q) = q'(t) = p(t)$,  so $D$ is indeed onto.

For (ii), as long as you limit members of $\mathbb{R}[t]$ to have a finite number of terms, you are good.

Comment: I think you want $p_kt^k$ or sum from $n=0$ to $k$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner of course, corrected, tyvm